# Gauss–Lucas theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, convex-analysis, barycentric-coordinates

Suppose that we have proven the following theorem :

Let P be a non constant complex polynomial. Then the convex hull of the roots of P' are included in the convex hull of the roots of P :

$ Conv(P') \subset Conv(P) $

Then how could we deduce the following ?

$ \forall v \in \mathbb{C} \: \: \: Conv(P') \subset Conv(P-v) $

Comment: Is $P'$ the derivative of $P$?

Comment: Observe that $(P-v)'=P'$. By Gauss-Lucas $Conv(P-v)\supset Conv((P-v)')=Conv(P')$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Yes.

Comment: @flan Thank you